# Load data into Hbase table using HBASE MAP REDUCE API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am very new for Hbase and Map Reduce API.
I am very confused with Map Reduce concepts. I need to Load text file into Hbase table using MAPReduce API. I googled some Examples but in that I can find MAPPER () not reducer method. I am confused with when to use mapper and when to use Reducer ().
 I am thinking in the way like :

1. TO write data to a Hbase we use mapper
2. TO read data from
   HBASE we use mapper and reducer(). please can any one clear me with
   detail explanation.
3. I am trying to load data from text file into
   HBASE table. I googled and tried some code but i dont know, how to
   load the text file and read in HBASE mapreduce API.

I really thank full for certain help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regard to your questions:

- The **Mapper** receives splits of data and returns a pair key, set<values>
- The **Reducer** receives the output of from the Mapper and generates a pair <key, value>

Generally, will be your *Reducer* task which will write results (to the filesystem or to HBase), but the Mapper can do that too. There are *MapReduce* jobs which don't require a *Reducer*. With regard to reading from HBase, it's the Mapper class that has the configuration from which table to read from. But there's nothing related a Mapper is a reader and Reducer a writer. This article ["HBase MapReduce Examples"](http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html) provides good examples about how to read from and write into HBase using *MapReduce*.

In any case, if what you need is to bulk import some .csv files into HBase, you don't really need to do it with a *MapReduce* job. You can do it directly with the [HBase API](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html). In pseudocode:

```
table = hbase.createTable(tablename, fields); 
foreach (File file: dir) {
   content = readfile(file);    
   hbase.insert(table, content); 
}
```

I wrote an [importer of .mbox files](https://github.com/dpino/Metamail/tree/master/enron-importer) into HBase. Take a look at the code, it may give you some ideas.

Once your data is imported into HBase, then you do need to code a *MapReduce* job to operate with that data.

Answer (score 1):

Using **HFileOutputFormat** with **CompleteBulkLoad** is best and fastest way to load data in HBase.
You will find sample code [here](http://databuff.blogspot.com/2013/11/bulk-load-data-in-hbase-table.html#.V3-BVut9744)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple responses of mine that address loading data into HBASE.

[What is the fastest way to bulk load data into HBase programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750764/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-bulk-load-data-into-hbase-programmatically/8751176#8751176)

[Writing to HBase in MapReduce using MultipleOutputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983122/writing-to-hbase-in-mapreduce-using-multipleoutputs/5983853#5983853)

EDIT: Adding additional link based on comment
This link might help make the file available for processing.
[Import external libraries in an Hadoop MapReduce script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984894/import-external-libraries-in-an-hadoop-mapreduce-script/5009808#5009808)

Comment: I need to Read raw Text file/csv file from system into map-reduce job and read the data which is available in the text file and store the retrieved data  it in Hbase table. the above links are not for right task

Comment: @user178900: Added a link that might address the additional need.

Comment: I need to read Csv File /Text file from a local system into mapreduce Job and store the data in htable. I cant find any methods to read a file from local system, can u please provide some samples, i am very new for Hadoop

Comment: @user178900 You can't read from the local file system. The data needs to be on the HDFS. You either need to put it there first and have that as the input or include it as a 'file' as my added link shows. Hadoop is a distributed system, it can't be sure that a file existing on machineA exists on machineB, so it does't read local files. (There's probably some hack to do it, but it's not the intent of hadoop) My suggestion is to put the file on the HDFS first, then use the concepts in the first 2 links.

Comment: My hadoop is on Remote Machine and i am creating an application in eclipse reading data from my local system like(d:workplace/input.csv). Cant i use the above link in Mapreduce and load data in Htable